# Make array from data in a laravel blade foreach loop

Tags: php, arrays, foreach, laravel-5.3, laravel-blade

I wish to submit a form where there are rows in a foreach loop by ticking the checkbox. When there is a row outside of the foreach loop I seem to receive the id data into my controller however when it is outside of the foreach loop it is just skipped. Here is my code sample? What am I missing?

```
 <form action="{{ url('/staff') }}" method="POST" role="form" id="form" class="form-horizontal">
    {{ csrf_field() }}
    @foreach ($items as $item)
     <tbody>        
       <tr>         
       <td >
        {{ $item->first_name }} {{ $item->last_name }}
       </td>

       <td class="center">
        <div class="checkbox-table">
         <label>
          <input name="item[]" value="{{ $item->id }}" type="checkbox" class="flat-grey">
        </label>
       </div>
    </td>
    </tr>

    @endforeach


    </tbody>
       <div>
        <button class="btn btn-yellow" type="submit">
         Save</i>
        </button>
       </div>

    </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Works by removing this from the input label.

```
class="flat-grey"
```